# Code not turning out, beginner struggling

Tags: javascript

I am learning to code and going through a program right now online. I have gotten stuck with a toggle button issue. Whenever I try to type toggle(position), it returns with an undefined value. What it should be doing is turning an object from true to false or false to true.

```
<script>
  
    var todos = [{todoText: 'item1', completed: false}, 
    {todoText: 'item2', completed: false}, 
    {todoText: 'item3', completed: false}]

    console.log(todos);
  
      function add(initialToDoText){
        todos.push({todotext: initialToDoText, completed: false})
        console.log(todos)
      }

    function edit(position, newValue) {
      todos[position].todoText = {todotext: newValue, completed: false}

      console.log(todos)
    }

    function removed(gone1) {
      todos.splice(gone1, 1)
      console.log(todos)
    };
    
    function toggle(position) {
      if (todos[position].completed === false) {
        todos[position].completed = true;
    } else {
      todos[position].completed = false

    }
    console.log(todos);
  }
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/r3hesd42/). Please create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question to help demonstrate.

Comment: We need to see your HTML

Comment: @elke_wtf There's no indication of any HTML.

Comment: I added snippet.

Comment: Hm, everything works fine. Michael, have I corrected your issue while adding snippet?

Comment: Keywords : "beginner", "struggling", "learning to code", and still there are people downvoting.... I don't understand.

Comment: @Romka I believe this is the main issue of Stack Overflow.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the code shown doesn't reproduce the issue described. According to community guidelines, the question is thereby not answerable and not useful. Downvotes and/or closure are arguably appropriate, but are not a reflection of human worth. Editing the question can make it more useful. In my opinion, troubleshooting concepts mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) are important tools for all coders.

Comment: @showdev you are right. I was just hoping about a bit much of humanity in this logical system :)
But according to "rules" you are totally right.

Comment: @Romka I hear you. I encourage the OP to help clarify so we can figure this one out :)

Answer (score 1):

The `toggle()` function does exactly what you expect, but since there is no return value it returns `undefined`. Since you are new to JavaScript you should know that console.log() does not return a value for the function it only writes to the console.
Visit [Javascript return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#syntax) for more information.

Comment: Nice and helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong!

When I was working in the google dev tools it was in the "error" section so it was only showing me the errors! love you all xoxo!

Comment: Nice! You found the solution by yourself. I wish you luck with your program.

Answer (score -1):

With 'position' variable I think you are trying 'item1' or 'item2' and that is why you get undefined value.
That's normal, todos['item1'] does not exist. It exists under this: todos[0]["todoText"].

Therefore you need first to find in which index item1 is and then try and change its completed attribute.

So, I would replace toggle function with this one:

```
   function toggle(position) {
          let results = [];
            for(let i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
                if (todos[i]['todoText'].indexOf(position) > -1) {
                     if (todos[i]['completed'] === true) {
                        todos[i]['completed'] = false;
                    } else {
                        todos[i]['completed'] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        console.log(todos);
      }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Different is just notation.

Comment: If I am correct with my assumption, then this solves exactly his problem. He does ask "What it should be doing is turning an object from true to false or false to true" in case you missed it. And if he had problems understanding console.log(), then he wouldn't focus his problem in toggle() alone. You should judge better before downvote.

Comment: In case you missed it, he has already done it using: todos[position].completed = true;